# iOS 8 Today Interface Builder

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, today-extension

I've programatically set the width and height of my Today widget, and those changes are reflected when I run my app on my phone. However in my storyboard, the height has not changed (so I can't really position objects properly).

[image]

How can I set the view size in IB? It doesn't let me change the width/height at the moment.

EDIT: This post is about how to set up the layout it in storyboard, not how to code the widget which I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the view in IB, click the ruler icon (Size inspector?), then there's a height field that you can change to whatever you want

Comment: yep worked perfectly. for some reason it only lets me change the size by clicking the arrows, not typing. thanks.

Comment: Then please file a bug ;)